# Single phase 2 wire motor... Can this be connected to household electrical wiring?

Tags: power-supply, power

Hi I have a soft ice cream machine which shows as240v but is a single phase motor.  It has a scotch block with two black wires and the earth separate.  Can this be attached to normal uk sockets via a wire and plug?
 Thanks

Comment: there should be a plate on the motor. what does it say?

Comment: Any documentation come with the device?

Comment: yeah, what AC frequency does the motor need?

Answer (score 1):

If the appliance shows a nameplate rating of 240V it is not clear why you would ask this question? On first appearance, it would seem obvious that it was intended for UK/European/230-240V mains power.

The "scotch block with two black wires and the earth separate" doesn't really tell us anything without a photo and description of what is connected there.

Answer (score -1):

In Costa Rica we have 110/220 volt distribution with three wires: two black and one earth. There are 110 volts from either black to earth and 220 volts between the two blacks (don't have to be black, it is just for your question). We have two type of plugs, 220 plugs for certain appliances (like the electric oven) and 110-volt plugs for lighting and other stuff. If I get a motor like yours I would just plug it into a 220-volt plug without worrying too much about it. The earth it to earth the housing. Regards.